# What exactly do the rx-vlan-offload and tx-vlan-offload ethtool options do?

Tags: networking, vlan, offloading

The ethtool manpage only gives a nebulous explanation:

```
   rxvlan on|off
          Specifies whether RX VLAN acceleration should be enabled

   txvlan on|off
          Specifies whether TX VLAN acceleration should be enabled
```

What exactly do the options accomplish, assuming you can enable them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, `rxvlan` and `txvlan` are aliases for the kernel features `rx-vlan-hw-parse` and `tx-vlan-hw-insert` respectively (see [`ethtool.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git/tree/ethtool.c)).

In the kernel they are translated to the netdev features `NETIF_F_HW_VLAN_CTAG_RX_BIT` and `NETIF_F_HW_VLAN_CTAG_TX_BIT`. (See [`net/core/ethtool.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/source/net/core/ethtool.c#L64))

To the best of my knowledge, the TX_BIT allows the NIC to add the VLAN tag during transmission without explicitly placing it in the packet. See the relevant code in the [VLAN driver](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11/source/net/8021q/vlan_dev.c#L589).

Similarly, when the RX_BIT is enabled, the NIC can strip the VLAN tag from incoming packets and let the driver place the information from the VLAN tag in the relevant skb.